# How to downgrade the version of the vespa engine installed in ec2 server

Tags: database, deployment, server, versioning, vespa

I have Vespa version  7.534.29 compiled with go1.15.14 on linux/amd64 how can i downgrade it to 7.220.14 as its causing my custom searchers to not work in production

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? Any warnings/errors in the vespa.log?

Comment: json is not supported and its not able to genrate log folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a new Vespa version is described at https://docs.vespa.ai/en/operations/live-upgrade.html. It could be an idea to try your custom searchers in an environment using the same Docker containers as in https://docs.vespa.ai/en/getting-started.html - to see if the problem is your build of Vespa or something else.